# GIT: Revert states - even in subrepositories

Tags: git

this is how I understand submodules: Independent repositories with states (commit-id's) that are recorded in a main repository to be able to revert the entire state at a particular point in time.

But if I am in the main repository, should'nt a checkout of a past commit ('detached HEAD') or branch lead to a checkout of the corresponding subrepositories state?

If I revert the project, the subrepos state doesn't change.

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logically, switching the revision checked out in a submodule at the same time you do a `git checkout` in your main repository would make sense in a lot of cases. However, sometimes, you don't want to do that, and for that reason (and probably others), the `git` developers have chosen to not make that an automatic part of `git checkout`. Instead, you have a two-step process, running `git checkout <something>` followed by `git submodule update` to get all your submodules adjusted to the currently checked out main revision. It's a little bit of a pain until you develop the habit, but it allows you to check out different revisions for review without the added performance burden of updating the submodule(s) every time, which can be significant in large projects with many submodules.

Comment: That's a cool feature. I made a "submodule update" directly in the subrepos without effect. Just doing it in the main repo and it works perfect. Thanks a lot!